# When to use Do/Does & Is in questions

Tags: questions, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

Primary sentence
This is applicable for all account

Which question form is correct and why?

> A) Is this applicable for all account?
>
> B) Does this applicable for all account ?

Comment: It's the one with all the same words, because it's the one with all the same words.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an auxiliary verb, you always invert:

- I must go. →  Must I go?
- I will be. →  Will I be?
- I should say it. →  Should I say it?
- I can swim. →  Can I swim?
- I am leaving. →  Am I leaving?
- I have done it. →  Have I done it?

The same happens with the verb "to be" even when it's not apparently auxiliary (although some linguists consider "to be" an auxiliary in this case too, partly for this reason):

- I am funny. →  Am I funny?

The same happens with "have got" and optionally with "have":

- I have got a cat. →  Have I got a cat?
- I have a fish. →  Do I have a fish? *or* Have I a fish? (The latter is less common, more formal, and rarely found at all in American English.)

For all other verbs, we add the dummy auxiliary verb "do" prior to inversion.  (You might say that we add it at the same time as inverting, but I prefer to think of it as a two-step process.)

- I like your cat. →  I do like your cat. →  Do I like your cat?
- I know what you mean. →  I do know what you mean. →  Do I know what you mean?

In short, the sentence "This is applicable" uses the verb "to be" and therefore you don't add the dummy verb "do" and you just invert:

- This is applicable. →  Is this applicable?

Answer (score 0):

None are correct -- including your primary sentence.

Correct:

- This is applicable for all accounts.
- Is this applicable for all accounts?

Comment: This does applicable for all the accounts ........Does this applicable for all accounts ? Is it correct version .

Comment: @user4084 No, **does** is only used with verbs, and *applicable* is not a verb.  Think about the statement: it is "It **is** applicable", not "it **does** applicable."

Comment: If you want to use a form of applicable, you can use the verb form: "Does this apply to all accounts?" (and note use of "to" as opposed to "for")